# Referencing the User model

Tags: django, django-models

In my Django projects I have two apps. Each app have it's own users and each reference different dbs. App1 User is inherited from django AbstractUser and it's the locally django-managed db, where as in App2 User inherited from User and is managed externally. Now while trying to runserver I'm getting following errors.

**App1**

*models.py*

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class ApiUser(AbstractUser):
  api_key = models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=True, unique=True)

  class Meta:
      db_table = 'app1_apiuser'
      app_label = 'app1'
```

**App2**

*models.py*

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class MyUser(User):
  my_key = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=255)

  class Meta:
      db_table = 'app2_myuser'
      managed = False
      app_label = 'app2'

class Device(models.Model):
  created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)

  class Meta:
      db_table = 'app2_device'
      managed = False
```

*settings.py*

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'app1.ApiUser'
```

**errors**

```
app1.ApiUser.groups: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'ApiUser.groups' clashes with reverse accessor for 'User.groups'.
    HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'ApiUser.groups' or 'User.groups'.
app1.ApiUser.user_permissions: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'ApiUser.user_permissions' clashes with reverse accessor for 'User.user_permissions'.
    HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'ApiUser.user_permissions' or 'User.user_permissions'.
app2.Device.created_by: (fields.E301) Field defines a relation with the model 'auth.User', which has been swapped out.
    HINT: Update the relation to point at 'settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL'.
app2.MyUser.user_ptr: (fields.E301) Field defines a relation with the model 'auth.User', which has been swapped out.
    HINT: Update the relation to point at 'settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL'.
```

Comment: I dont think you can have different `User` models for different apps. Maybe I am wrong.

Comment: @SachinKukreja I'm also not sure about it but these links says otherwise
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model
https://wsvincent.com/django-referencing-the-user-model/

Comment: They don't say anything of the sort. Once you've swapped out the User model, you can't use it in any app.

Comment: so what is the best way to handle this. I'm trying to import models from Project A into Project B. Project A has `User` and Project B has `AbstractUser`.